# SPSS Python Custom Extension Command Debugging

Tags: python, debugging, spss

I have created a Custom Extension Command in Python. I installed it, but as expected I am getting errors (quote from SPSS log output - the only way I know for debugging Python programs in SPSS):

```
Extension command  TEST_EXTENSION  could not be loaded. The module or a module that it requires may be missing, or there may be syntax errors in it.
```

The error is probably from the `.xml`or from the `Run(args)` function. The `CustomFunction()` I am implementing was tested thoroughly.

What would be a good practice for debugging this, and the other potential errors ? The official [IBM-SPSS-Statistics-Extension-Command](https://developer.ibm.com/predictiveanalytics/wp-content/uploads/sites/48/2015/04/Writing-IBM-SPSS-Statistics-Extension-Commands1.pdf) says to

> set the
>   SPSS_EXTENSIONS_RAISE
>   environment variable to "true"

but I don't know how to do that, nor of this will work regardless of the source of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@horace

You set the environment variable on Windows via the Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables.  The exact wording varies with different Windows versions.  I usually choose System variables, although either will usually work.  You need to restart Statistics after that.  Once you have set this variable, errors in the Python code will produce a traceback.  The traceback is ordinarily suppressed as it is of no use to users, but it is very helpful for developers.

The traceback only appears for errors in the Python code.  The "could not be loaded" error you reported happens before Python gets control, so no traceback would be produced.  There are two common causes for this error.  The first is that the xml file defining the extension command or the corresponding Python module was not found by Statistics.  The extension command definitions are loaded at Statistics startup or by running the EXTENSION command.  Execute SHOW EXT. from the Syntax Editor to see the places where Statistics looks for extension files.

The second cause is a syntax error in the Python code.  Run
begin program.
import yourmodule
end program.
to see if any errors are reported.

More generally, there are two useful strategies for debugging.  The first is to run the code in external mode, where you run the code from Python.  That way you can step through the code using your IDE or the plain Python debugger.  See the programmability documentation for details.  There are some limitations on what can be done in external mode, but it is often a good solution.

The second is to use an IDE that supports remote debugging.  I use Wing IDE, but there are other IDEs that can do this.  That lets me jump into the debugger from within Statistics, step through the Python code, and do all the other things you want in a debugger.

HTh